# WPF Custom datagrid column header

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to create a Custom dataGrid DataGridTextColumn like the sketch below:

[image: Sketch]

The Red rectangles are TextBox and are used to search within the column.

so far i have implemented a datagrid like this (simplify Version):

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="CompassLogDataGrid"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=DataGridStyle}"
              IsTextSearchEnabled="True">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource IdCell}"
                                x:Name="ID"
                                Header="ID"
                                Foreground="Black"
                                Binding="{Binding ID}"
                                DisplayIndex="0" />

                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DateGTC"
                                Header="Date"
                                Binding="{Binding DateString}"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource DateGTCCell}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns

    </DataGrid
```

I have no idea how to create those textBoxes. Any clue would be appreciate it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`DataGridTemplateColumn` is what you are looking for. You can customize the template as per your need -

```
 <DataGrid>
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBox BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" Margin="5"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

With sample `ItemsSource` it gives this look -

[image]

**EDIT**

In case you want to customize the header, you need to provide `HeaderTemplate` for your column like this -

```
   <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                Header="{Binding HeaderName}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource=
                                         {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                       Margin="5"/>
                            <TextBox BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3"
                                     Width="50" Margin="5"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here's the look -

[image]

Comment: I can see where the red TextBox is created by the xaml above, but how would you get to it's contents from the code?

Comment: @Steve Would you not just bind its `Text` property to a property on the viewmodel like normal? In fact this answer even shows how to do that. Or if you need to detect when it changes, use the `TextChanged` event (or even just subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event)?