# HorizontalAlignment not working on ComboBox in DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGridTextColumn` whose header consists of a `TextBlock` and a `ComboBox`. I would like the `TextBlock` to be left aligned and the `ComboBox` to be right-aligned. When I try setting that on `ComboBox` using `HorizontalAlignment = "Right"`, it does not work! For the header I tried with `StackPanel` as well as a `Grid` for containing the `TextBlock` and `ComboBox`. What I am doing wrong?

```
    <DataGrid 
        CanUserSortColumns="True"
        IsReadOnly="True">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Money" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding comboBoxItems}" SelectedIndex="0">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>

            </DataGridTextColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Attempt with Grid:

```
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Money" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding comboBoxItems}" SelectedIndex="0">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>

                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

**EDIT 1:** I would like the ComboBox to be stretched if the column is dragged to increase the column width. Otherwise atleast the ComboBox should align to the right if the column is dragged on the right side.

**EDIT 2:** The important thing here is that when I drag the column to increase its width, the ComboBox should fall on the right side.

Comment: could you post your attempt with `Grid`? Thanks

Comment: Just added the grid attempt...

Comment: here is what you need [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175546/wpf-custom-datagrid-column-header/15175706#15175706)

Comment: Add Width from safi's example to you grid and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="120">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}}">
                <TextBlock Text="LLLLL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
                <TextBlock Text="RRRRR" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `DockPanel` instead of `StackPanel`.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TextBlock Text="Money" VerticalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        <ComboBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Have you copied the whole example?

Comment: You didn't supply the example code earlier. Anyways I did the same thing you added later and it doesn't work. The ComboBox stays on the left side!

Comment: Works pretty fine for me. Are you sure you removed combobox's Width and set LastChildFill="True"?

Comment: Yes I did add all that!