# WPF simulate shared headers in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my application I would like to have table like these : http://www.ncaa.com/standings/basketball-men/d1

I've managed to have the shared columns (in the example "Conference" and "overall") adding a grid like in this example : http://akashsoni7.blogspot.fr/2013/01/create-multilevel-header-in-wpf-grid.html

However I can't manage to add only one vertical grid (between the column "PCT" and "W" in the example), is there a way to achieve this in wpf's datagrid ?
(i'm talking about the gray line)

Thank you

Comment: Are talking about the thick grey border? Grey line betwn the PCT and W

Comment: Yes ! I'll edit my post sorry

Comment: Have a look at [DataGridColumnHeader Template](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15175706/2029607). HTH