# On a WPF DataGrid bound to a DataTable, how can I generically change the Column Header template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

From an interface with another part of my project, I have a `DataTable` object which contains a variable number of columns and rows. I am trying to design a `DataGrid` that will show the table via binding, but customize the column headers for each column with some options (ex a `TextBox` under the header).

This is very similar to a previously asked question [WPF Custom datagrid column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175546/wpf-custom-datagrid-column-header), except that I don't want to define the columns in WPF; but rather a template for columns which propagates across each column during binding.

The previous answer gets the right look, but when a `DataGrid` with that WPF style is bound to a `DataTable`, the result is a static single column with the additional red boardered `TextBox`, plus a bunch of bound columns which do not contain the textbox:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                            Header="{Binding HeaderName}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource=
                                     {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                   Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3"
                                 Width="50" Margin="5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Instead of having the WPF above create a first column, how do I change it to have that specify the template of how bound columns should be rendered?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you turned off the autogeneration of columns? If you want to control not only which columns are displayed but how those columns are displayed you need to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Chris- though I think I want autogeneration of colums here (I want the databinding to create columns, but by a template that I specify)- I want to control how columns are displayed but not which columns are displayed.

Comment: Ah. I think you'll have to define the template elsewhere and reference in in your grid - but I'm not sure how you'd do that. If you do it this way you *have* to turn autogeneration off and specify the columns explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in Style

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource=
                                           {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                <TextBox BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3"
                                         Width="50" Margin="5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

There seems to be a "MainHeader" for the entire DataGrid also,
note the HasContent Trigger to eliminate this header from the Style.

Comment: Thanks, @Funk, that worked very well, especially the use of the HasContent trigger to keep the right-hand empty space from having the same template. As a quick follow-up, is there any way to bind the first TextBlock to properties on the correct DataColumn, instead of the Content which has propagated through?

Comment: @JacobPitts Sure, try <TextBlock Text="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>